# How do I prevent spammers from exploiting my Google App Engine form that sends email to others?

Tags: forms, google-app-engine, spam-prevention

I'm making a quick Google App Engine program that presents a publicly available form that users can fill out with their name and email address, then can enter a friend's name and e-mail address.  The application pulls in the data via POST, then sends a pre-formatted e-mail like 'Hi, , your friend  wants to invite you...'

What should I be doing to prevent spammers from exploiting this publicly facing e-mail sending program?  Is there a good resource for best-practices in this field?  I've spent a few hours searching, but I haven't really found anything definitive...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Principally creating a *publicly available form*  that anyone can use to *send[s] a pre-formatted e-mail* is another name for creating a spam machine.

You can mitigate by making it harder for non-humans to use it, `recaptcha` is the typical way to achieve this.

Comment: Is the problem mitigated further if it just takes in an e-mail address and sends a pre-formatted e-mail, so potential spammers wouldn't have a place to put any links or information?

Comment: There are (roughly) two kinds of spam: 1.) Ad or fraud spam 2.) (D)DOS spam. Preformatting helps against 1.) but not against 2.)

Comment: Thanks! I didn't even think about (D)DOS spam - Our form will only be used a couple times a day by legitimate users anyhow, so I'll look into ways of intelligently choking app use volume.

Answer (score 1):

You could send a confirmation email to the *sender* and require a secondary action (like clicking a link) before sending the email.  Or, if you expect your users to return, ask them to sign up (with a similar confirmation) before allowing them to send email.

Answer (score 0):

I would first impose some limit to the # of email addresses a specific user/IP can send. This won't solve the problem but will limit the damage in case someone does try to send spam to 1000 emails.

Second, you could try sending the emails in small batches if an user puts in a lot of email addresses. Send 5 at a time, and monitor to see if there's any spam complaints (you can probably automate this somehow). If no complaints after 2 days, keep sending the rest.